# Blazor Web Assembly and Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to implement some kind of authentication for my Blazor Web Assembly application. I have an Identity Server 4 instance running on some server, it seems to be completely operational.

My problem is that in the guide above, the `returnUrl` that is passed to identity server is obviously not a local url. By digging into Identity Server's code, I found that it will always fail to login a user if the return url is not local :

```
        public async Task<AuthorizationRequest> GetAuthorizationContextAsync(string returnUrl)
        {
            var result = await _returnUrlParser.ParseAsync(returnUrl);

            if (result != null)
            {
                _logger.LogTrace("AuthorizationRequest being returned");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogTrace("No AuthorizationRequest being returned");
            }

            return result;
        }
```

In the code above from `DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService`, `ParseAsync()` calls `IsLocal()` which causes `result` to be null, which in turn, produces the following in my logs:

```
2020-09-28T19:37:25.932782009Z [2020-09-28T19:37:25.9324455+00:00] [VRB] [] [IdentityServer4.Services.OidcReturnUrlParser] returnUrl is not valid
2020-09-28T19:37:25.932807561Z [2020-09-28T19:37:25.9325314+00:00] [VRB] [] [IdentityServer4.Services.OidcReturnUrlParser] No AuthorizationRequest being returned
2020-09-28T19:37:25.932817324Z [2020-09-28T19:37:25.9325559+00:00] [VRB] [] [IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService] No AuthorizationRequest being returned
```

Could someone point me towards what I'm not understanding here ? Can I provide any more information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your issue is about LocalUrl, it seems that you set it wrong if you followed the guid.

If you are following default settings, its enough to have client config on IDS4 like this:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "wasmappauth-client",
                    ClientName = "Blazor Webassembly App Client",
                    RequireClientSecret = false,

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,

                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5005" },
                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5005/authentication/login-callback" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5005/authentication/logout-callback" },

                    AllowedScopes = {"openid", "profile"},
                }
```

Here is my blog post which I explained same thing but in simpler wording:  https://nahidfa.com/posts/blazor-webassembly-authentication-and-authorization-with-identityserver4/

Edit: About check for local URLs, its it [by design on IDS4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2594#issuecomment-426998142)

Comment: You were right, something was not set up correctly, I must have missed some step while following the guide. But I realized it would be faster to just trash the whole thing and start from scratch... Anyways, works now. Thanks